# Как создать библиотеку .so с кодом CUDA?

Tags: cuda, so

Пытаюсь создать динамическую библиотеку so с кодом CUDA для Linux. Пытаюсь скомпилировать:

```
nvcc CudaLib.cu -shared -o CudaLib.so -arch=native
```

Получаю ошибку:

> перемещение R_X86_64_32S для «.rodata» не может использоваться при
> создании общий объект; перекомпилируйте с параметром -fPIC

Понятно, что для компиляции нужен параметр -fPIC, но в nvcc он не поддерживается. Если написать

```
nvcc CudaLib.cu -shared -fPIC -o CudaLib.so -arch=native
```

то будет ошибка:

> Unknown option '-fPIC'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл ответ.
Для того, чтобы добавить флаг -fPIC нужно использовать -Xcompiler=-fPIC.

Таким образом, строка компиляции будет

```
nvcc CudaLib.cu -shared -Xcompiler=-fPIC -o CudaLib.so -arch=native
```